# Does Python have null safety support?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does Python have null safety?

Something like Kotlin operators such as `"?"` or `"!!"`. If not, is this a feature on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PEP 505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) proposes **None-aware operators**, but it currently seems to be in limbo.

You may want to read through this [discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-September/036535.html) back from 2015.